Repository in pom.xml not opening up
This repository is not opening up:
https://artifactory.oraclecorp.com/artifactory/jcenter-cache/
I am using dependencies of this repo in my maven project.Is there any alternative for this repository?
My build fails with this error currently:


while trying to load the maven ,its unable to access this repository and hence not loading.

What artifacts do you need from this repo?

The error message: No route to host.. network issue...

The last error message says you're in offline mode, that would explain why maven cannot reach your repo.
We cannot see the maven command you ran, but possibly you are using the -o (offline) parameter ?
For the future, please restrain from posting screen captures, they are hard to read / parse, and details are easily cropped or overlooked. You can post the commands / output instead, like so.
